# Multiple warnings and errors when refreshing applications in snap

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, fonts

I have a problem with Ubuntu 20.04. For some reason, I can't update software from GUI. The error refers to the `snap`. I started from following commands (I was not sure when `apt update` should be executed so I run it twice):

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt autoremove --purge
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt update
```

Then I tried to refresh `snap`:

```
sudo snap refresh
```

which just generates a bunch of errors, which seems to be exactly the same but refer to different applications in the `snap`. Here are errors:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "zoom-client" snap if present (run hook "configure": 
-----
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 6: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 7: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 7: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 9: unknown element "description"
-----)
```

Then the others seem to be different by snap ID and app (other 5 apps). Here is the example of the second error:

```
- Run configure hook of "chromium" snap if present (run hook "configure": 
-----
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 6: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 7: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 7: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 9: unknown element "description"
/snap/chromium/1424/snap/command-chain/hooks-configure-desktop: line 43: 14578 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) "${SNAP_DESKTOP_RUNTIME}/usr/bin/fc-cache" --force --system-only --verbose
-----)
```

I can't figure out how to sort it.

I also asked the same question [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/kbpgfh/unable_to_update_software/). Apparently `sudo apt dist-upgrade` broke system and is a caused all this because *it forces removal of packages to allow installation of other packages regardless of whether those being removed are essential to Linux working*. I thought `dist-upgrade` was a safe command.

---

EDIT.

```xml
  1 <?xml version="1.0"?>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  2 <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
  3 <!-- /etc/fonts/fonts.conf file to configure system font access -->
  4 <fontconfig>
  5 
  6     <its:rules xmlns:its="http://www.w3.org/2005/11/its" version="1.0">
  7         <its:translateRule translate="no" selector="/fontconfig/*[not(self::description)]"/>
  8     </its:rules>
  9 
 10     <description>Default configuration file</description>
```

Comment: I run the command `sudo apt -f install` and get no errors. The last line is `0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.` However, I've got all the errors in question when I run `sudo snap refresh`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comments, anyway!

Comment: Edit your question to show us the first 10 lines of `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: The error messages seem to be complaining about a valid config file (no typos), so try reinstalling fontconfig: `sudo apt install --reinstall fontconfig`

Comment: This is what I tried before: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall --purge fontconfig fontconfig-config`. I think it doesn't makes difference to what you have suggested but it did not work. There was a discussion on arch linux 2 years ago: `https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235643`. I can't see if they shared any solution to this.

Comment: The Arch discussion may --or may not-- be relevant. A similar-seeming problem might have a very different cause. That thread looks like it had a definite resolution to me: Folks were using the wrong-version library, and when they started using the right-version library the problem went away.

Comment: Is there anything additional information you can offer so I can duplicate your problem in my 20.04 test environment? My fontconfig works properly. I don't get any of the errors that you get. If we cannot reproduce the issue, then identifying the actual problem becomes unlikely.

Comment: I have not done any sort of hacking. All commands were system like. The only things I can think of are: (1) the system was upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and (2) I also installed the newest TexLive 2020 which adds a couple of fonts.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still interested in the answer, I have just found the erroneous file. In my case it was an extra font file `/etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf` linked to a font file installed with the TexLive 2020: `/path/to/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf`. I suppose any older(ish) application that installs incompatible font files will cause this issue sooner or later.

The sort out the issue, I removed the file, removed and rebuilt cache:

```bsh
rm -f ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
sudo rm -f /var/cache/fontconfig/*
sudo fc-cache -rv
```

After this, `snap` seems to work again.

---

EDIT.

There is a post on [Snapcraft](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapped-app-not-loading-fonts-on-fedora-and-arch/12484/25) that suggests running `fc-cache -rv` instead of `sudo fc-cache -rv`. I don't know the exact difference between executing this command as root and as a user but I had to run it as root.

For TexLive users, I can still link the file and rebuild font cache once you have updated snap because applications seem to work. However, every time I want to install something I have to repeat the routine.

Hope it helps.