# Reinstalling snap

Tags: snap

I have already asked one [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299991/multiple-warnings-and-errors-when-refreshing-applications-in-snap) regarding issues in Ubuntu 20.04 with `snap`. I haven't really got any answer but a suggestion that the issues might be with the `snap` itself. I was trying to find out if we have an option to repair / reinstall the whole snap as if it was installed with fresh system but I couldn't find anything wile "googling" the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Your previous question seems to be about fontconfig errors. In general, read error cascades from top to bottom, and start looking for causes near the top.

Comment: I googled `fontconfig` before and found a few answers. I tried plenty of commands: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, `sudo apt-get clean`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall --purge fontconfig fontconfig-config` but nothing worked. I am really out of options. I thought this could be related to snap itself but everyone suggests it is the system. I cannot figure out what else I could do. This is unfortunately beyond me.

Comment: It's not beyond you, or anybody. This is learning. To me, it looks like re-installing snapd is the wrong track. I doubt that it will fix a fontconfig problem. But I've been wrong before.

Comment: OK. I'll keep searching for fontconfig errors and try to find something. Thanks.

Comment: I did comment on your previous question, asking for additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `sudo apt purge snapd && sudo apt install snapd` to reinstall snap. I don't believe your issue is with snap, but if you wish to reinstall snap, this is how you do it.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to umount any system or turn off any deamon before doing that?

Comment: No you don't. After reinstalling, I recommend rebooting to make sure everything is back to normal. I'm always glad to help!